# WPF async await TcpClient/TcpListener sample

Tags: c#, tcp, async-await

I want to build a robust and highly scalable client server system. Here what I have so far(an echo server as my base of implementation)

My Server

```
    private void startServer_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (anyIP.IsChecked == true)
        {
            listener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, Int32.Parse(serverPort.Text));
            Logger.Info("Ip Address : " + IPAddress.Any + " Port : " + serverPort.Text);
        }
        else
        {
            listener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Parse(serverIP.Text), Int32.Parse(serverPort.Text));
            Logger.Info("Ip Address : " + serverIP.Text + " Port : " + serverPort.Text);
        }
        try
        {
            listener.Start();
            Logger.Info("Listening");
            HandleConnectionAsync(listener, cts.Token);
        }
        //finally
        //{
            //cts.Cancel();
            //listener.Stop();
            //Logger.Info("Stop listening");
        //}

        //cts.Cancel();
    }

    async Task HandleConnectionAsync(TcpListener listener, CancellationToken ct)
    {
        while (!ct.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            Logger.Info("Accepting client");
            //TcpClient client = await listener.AcceptTcpClientAsync();
            TcpClient client = await listener.AcceptTcpClientAsync();
            Logger.Info("Client accepted");
            EchoAsync(client, ct);
        }

    }

    async Task EchoAsync(TcpClient client, CancellationToken ct)
    {
        var buf = new byte[4096];
        var stream = client.GetStream();
        while (!ct.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            var amountRead = await stream.ReadAsync(buf, 0, buf.Length, ct);
            Logger.Info("Receive " + stream.ToString());
            if (amountRead == 0) break; //end of stream.
            await stream.WriteAsync(buf, 0, amountRead, ct);
            Logger.Info("Echo to client");
        }
    }

    private void stopServer_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        cts.Cancel();
        listener.Stop();
        Logger.Info("Stop listening");
    }
```

My Client

```
    private void connect_Click(object sender, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        IPAddress ipAddress;
        int port;

        //TODO Check if ip address is valid
        ipAddress = IPAddress.Parse(serverIP.Text);
        //TODO port range is 0-65000
        port = int.Parse(serverPort.Text);

        StartClient(ipAddress, port);
    }

    private static async void StartClient(IPAddress serverIpAddress, int port)
    {
        var client = new TcpClient();
        //can i try/catch to catch await exception?
        try
        {
            await client.ConnectAsync(serverIpAddress, port);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Logger.Info(e);                
        }
        Logger.Info("Connected to server");
        using (var networkStream = client.GetStream())
        using (var writer = new StreamWriter(networkStream))
        using (var reader = new StreamReader(networkStream))
        {
            writer.AutoFlush = true;
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                Logger.Info("Writing to server");
                await writer.WriteLineAsync(DateTime.Now.ToLongDateString());
                Logger.Info("Reading from server");
                var dataFromServer = await reader.ReadLineAsync();
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(dataFromServer))
                {
                    Logger.Info(dataFromServer);
                }

            }
        }
        if (client != null)
        {
            client.Close();
            Logger.Info("Connection closed");
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 5):

1. The general issue with your code is that your client and server implementations reside in your control's code-behind. It is always a good idea to separate business logic from UI.
2. This is copy-paste:

   ```
   if (anyIP.IsChecked == true)
   {
       listener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, Int32.Parse(serverPort.Text));
       Logger.Info("Ip Address : " + IPAddress.Any + " Port : " + serverPort.Text);
   }
   else
   {
       listener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Parse(serverIP.Text), Int32.Parse(serverPort.Text));
       Logger.Info("Ip Address : " + serverIP.Text + " Port : " + serverPort.Text);
   }
   ```

   can be refactored to:

   ```
   var ip = anyIP.IsChecked == true ? IPAddress.Any : IPAddress.Parse(serverIP.Text);
   var port = Int32.Parse(serverPort.Text);
   listener = new TcpListener(ip, port);
   Logger.Info(String.Format("Ip Address : {0} Port : {1}", ip, port));
   ```
3. Its a good style to prefix fields with underscore, so they can be distinguished from local variables. So it should be `_listener` instead of `listener`.
4. You should shut down your server on exit.
5. Yes, as long, as you await the call you can catch exceptions.

Comment: Thank you. 1 and 2. I write it as fast as i can and i know its ugly. 3. I didnt know that. Thanks. 4. Youre right. 5. Thank you for that confirmation.